# How to set Textview to start at same column in all the row without hard coding margin left

Tags: android

I have this layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/productName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mrp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sellPrice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quantity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Problem is second text view in inner layout not starting at same column. It depends on the length of first textView in same layout.

Is there any android way to fix this?

Comment: What are you asking, exactly? Specifically, what column? You only have one row of TextViews. I don't see anything that could be construed as columns.

Comment: This Layout i am using for listView. So first textview is starting at proper place. But depending on the length of this, second and third are not in same column for other products in listview

Comment: Well, you've got the `layout_weight`s already, so just set their `layout_width`s to `0dp`, instead of `wrap_content`.

Comment: @MikeM. Perfect. This solves the problem. Thanks a lot.